# How to stop a user doing Ctrl-Z in Python shell

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x

When executing code in the shell, using <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> will 'undo' the last print line on Windows. I was wondering if there was a way to prevent a user doing this. e.g.

Having the code:

```
    print("Hello")
    print("How are you feeling Today")
```

will run like this in the shell:

```
Hello
How are you feeling Today
```

hitting <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> will remove the output `How are you feeling Today`

Comment: What do you mean by *undo the last print line*? On *NIX, hitting `Ctrl+Z` will stop the interpreter process. On Windows, it will exit the interpreter (when you hit `Enter` afterwards). It should not "undo" anything.

Comment: e.g. if you print "hello", Ctrl-Z will remove that line of code. If you print "hello" then "hi", it will just remove "hi".

Comment: >>> print('hello')`^Z`
[1]+  Stopped                 python3

Comment: What GUI do you use? Is it IDLE? The meaning of the keyboard shortcut depends on context: [`Ctrl+Z` is EOF on Windows or "suspend" on Unix on the command-line. It is "undo" in many GUI applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z)

Comment: This is using windows EOF.

Comment: "e.g. if you print "hello", Ctrl-Z will remove that line of code" ....no. No, it won't.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your question is badly worded because you are saying 'executing' when you should be saying 'entering' and 'print' when you should say 'enter', and 'line' when you should say 'word' or 'edit unit'.  Consequently, you are getting comments that apply to what you wrote rather than what you should have written.

I also conclude that you are not using the console interpreter.  I base this on this response of yours: "if you print "hello", Ctrl-Z will remove that line of code. If you print "hello" then "hi", it will just remove "hi".  This does not describe the console interpreter, whose only 'undo' keys are Backspace and Delete.

It does describe, for instance, the behavior of Idle.  If you enter 'hello' but do not hit Enter, ^Z deletes the word.  If you enter "Hello, hi", ^Z deletes 'hi'.  A second ^Z deletes the edit unit ', '.  A third ^Z deletes 'hello'.  A fourth ^Z, with nothing after the '>>> ' prompt, does nothing.  It does not delete previous statements or the output from their execution.

^Z is a standard code for Undo in text editors, at least on Windows.  By default, Idle follows this standard.  To answer your question: Idle lets you bind different keys to  Undo (see Options -> Idle preferences -> Keys) but I do not believe you can unbind ^Z without binding some other key.  As far as I know, most other editors will not let you change the key bindings.